# What word would be used for someone who shoots video?

Tags: single-word-requests

I used to work as a guy who used video camera to shoot events (ice hockey games). As a non-native English speaker I have struggled to find a word to describe it. So far I have used "video recorder" but that is feels like little silly 'cause it's VCR.

Comment: [Cameraman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cameraman) is likely your best bet and is most commonly heard in general use.  Alternatives are [Videographer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Videographer) and [Cinematographer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cinematographer), both of which are more specific and relatively newer terms (spellchecker doesn't even recognize Videographer, though it does recognize cinematographer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the film industry it is called *[camera operator](http://www.imdb.com/glossary/C)* or *cameraman*.

Comment: I'm gonna fly with *cameraman*, it feels like closest to what I did.

Answer (score 21):

You can describe him as a *videographer* (like photographer).

[image: "Keep calm and hire a wedding videographer"]

Comment: I see you type faster!

Comment: That is indeed the modern fancy name. Back in the day they were just "cameramen"

Comment: To use it correctly, it has to be in quotes, e.g.  ["videographer"](http://www.homestarrunner.com/sbemail205.html).  But I'd venture that the word is about doing more than just shooting.  It depends on how much you do... if you manage lighting, and editing, and do the titles and "effects" that would be a videographer.  There are more specific titles if you do only one of those.

Comment: @HostileFork: Disagree about the quotes; it's an accepted term these days and I'd bet on it being in at least one serious dictionary. I agree that the term implies not only running the camera but directing/interviewing (when appropriate), picking the shots, and producing/editing the raw footage into final form.

Comment: @keshlam The quotes was joking, the Strong Bad link should show.  The rest of the points were intentional.

Comment: @keshlam Confirmed: it's in the OED as a derivative of *videogram*.

Answer (score -1):

The English world is your Oyster! We have more words than any other language and not merely because we count most technical words as English words.

To answer this properly, though I really need to know what sort of work that you did. Right now you could just as easily be a cinematographer and a pornographer. From the way that you asked the question, it sounds like you are working on a resume, or some other professional document, so I would look up the actual word for you job position. If it's less professional, have some fun with it. You might have captured weddings, filmed riots and worked as the videographer for a music video.

Comment: I thought the same too -the terms are very specific to the work

Comment: I was taking video of ice hockey games.

Comment: I would use: Sports Videographer

Answer (score -1):

**[Video Photographer](https://www.wordnik.com/words/video%20photographer)**: A videographer who utilizes advanced photographic techniques to capture and create video images.

&

**[Videographer](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/videography)** the art or process of making films with a video camera.

Comment: No, that's _videography_. Videographer is the thing described first, and I have never heard of a "video photographer".